# TSQL to find out what SSRS Reports should have run between two dates/times

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

SSRS was accidentally turned off for a period of time.

How can I find out what Reports should have run?

Ideally I'd like some T-SQL to just query the tables and tell me what SSRS Reports should have run between two dates/times. I'm running SQL Server 2016.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like this script here will at least get you the data in one place. From there, I'm sure you can further manipulate the data to see what you want. As you may have guessed, to get this into a query where you just pop in a `@start` and `@end` variable would be a little messy I think. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/SSRS-Schedule-in-Readable-2ec993a9

Comment: Thanks! That's a great start. It seems to be missing the hour and minutes of execution. But this is heading in the right direction.